# when to use expression ${} in tag attributes values in Grails framework?

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to know how can I know when to pass the value of attributes with an expression ${} and where not.

For example, in the next tag call why `template` and `model` attribute values are passed without ${} but `collection` attribute value is passed with ${}.

`<g:render template="displaybook" model="['book':book,'author':author]" collection="${books}" />`

I would like to learn how to read the grails tags documentation in this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `${}` is only used for expressions that need to be evaluated, not for string literals.

```
<g:render template="displaybook" model="['book':book,'author':author]" collection="${books}" />
```

"displaybook" is a literal string, not a variable reference, so it doesn't make sense to put it in `${}`.

"books" is a variable reference, so it does make sense to put it in `${}`.

There is special handling when passing a literal collection like `['book':book,'author':author]`.  The parser will recognize the surrounding `[...]` and will evaluate the contents as an expression, not a string literal, so the `${}` isn't necessary there.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

See, if as the above answer says, you use ${} to evaluate something, for example this: "${book.author.name.toString()}", will return "Stephen King" for example, but if you put it like this "book.author.name.toString()" it will simply give you "book.author.name.toString()" this as a result. In addition, the symbol [something: 4, otherSomething: "what up"] is the same as this in java:

```
LinkedTreeMap<String,Object> map = new LinkedTreeMap<String,Object>();
map.put("something",4);
map.put("otherSomething","whats up");
```

It's just a veryyyyy easier way of creating a map without all the casting work, and stuff (that's one of the reasons groovy is so cool).

You can also do something like this:

```
  def map = [:]
  public void getObject(key){
  if(map."${key}")
     println(map."${key}") //this will print the object not the key,  getObject("mobile") would print cellphone not "mobile" understand? That's awsome!
}
```

That means you can use runtime keys from variables =D.

That's it hope I have helped